# using Java to insert and update data in jsp page and save into database

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, sql

I have been trying to solve this for few days and I need help. My system require me to allow user to edit the existing database in the jsp page and user need to click save after updating/inserting new data. My problem is that the query does not appear in my console and my save button is not functioning and the data does not inserted into the database.

[image: table]

```
solcQuery pcr=new solcQuery(uif);
String projectTitle = pcr.getProjPhaseName(co_no,proj_cde,phase);
List<String> storeForm = new ArrayList<String>();

if(request.getParameter("saveForm")!=null){ 
  System.out.println("saveform: " + request.getParameter("saveForm"));
if(request.getParameter("saveForm").equals("YES")){
    storeForm.add(request.getParameter("trckDate"));//0
    storeForm.add(request.getParameter("trckRmks"));//1
    pcr.insertcrdtdf(storeForm, co_no);
} else if (request.getParameter("saveForm").equals("NO")){
    storeForm.add(request.getParameter("trckDate"));//0
    storeForm.add(request.getParameter("trckRmks"));//1
    pcr.updcrdtdf1(storeForm, co_no, proj_cde,phase);
}


if(request.getParameter("action")!=null){
  String trckDte = request.getParameter("trckDte");
  String trckRmks = request.getParameter("trckRmks");
  pcr.updtrckDet(storeForm, proj_cde, co_no, lotNum, trckTyp, trckDte, trckRmks, phase, purcNum, 
trckNum);

 
 <script>

 function confirmation(){   
 
 
 var trckDte = document.getElementById("trckDte").value;
 var trckRmks = document.getElementById("trckRmks").value;
 
 alert("Update records");

 console.log("trckDte"+ trckDte);
 console.log("trckRmks"+ trckRmks);

 var check = "OK";
 if(trckDte=="" || trckRmks==""){
     check = "NOT OK";
 }
 console.log(check);
 if(check == "NOT OK"){
    
 } else { 
     <%if(checkProj.size()==0){ %>
     document.getElementById("saveForm").value = "YES"; //insert new
     <%} else if(checkProj.size()==1){ %>
     document.getElementById("saveForm").value = "NO"; //update
     <%}%>
     if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this record?')) {
     $('#spaloan').submit();
     } else {
         
     }
 }           


 function savedesc(date, remarks){
 var newdate = document.getElementById("newdate").value;
 if (confirm('Are you sure you want to change the description from '+ date+ " 
 to " + newdate + 
 "?")) {    
 document.getElementById("date_new").value=newdate;
 document.getElementById("remarks").value=remarks;
 $('#redirect').submit(); 
 } else {
     
 }
 }

 </script>
 </head>

<body>

<%
String[][] strckList = 
pcr.get_sTrckList(co_no,proj_cde,phase,trckTyp,lotNum,purcNum);
int ila = strckList.length;
System.out.println("120620  :" +co_no + proj_cde + phase + trckTyp + 
lotNum + purcNum);
System.out.println("120620-B:" +ila);
%>


<form id="spaloan" action="SPALoan.jsp" method="POST">  
<input type="hidden" name="proj_cde" id="proj_cde" value="<%=proj_cde%>">
<input type="hidden" name="phase"   id="phase"   value="<%=phase%>">
<input type="hidden" name="lotNum"   id="lotNum"   value="<%=lotNum%>">
<input type="hidden" name="co_no" id="co_no" value="<%=co_no%>">
<input type="hidden" name="remarks" id="remarks" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="saveForm" name="saveForm" value="">  

<div class="text-right mb-3" >
         <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" id="btn-save" 
         onclick="confirmation()">SAVE</button> 
</div>  

<thead>
  
        <tr>
        
            <th style="width:2%">No</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Description</th>
            <th style="width:5%">Date</th>
            <th style="width:15%">Remarks</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <%
    
    for(int j = 0; j < strckList.length; j++){
       String[] trck = new String[4];   
      
               
       trck[0] = strckList[j][0]; //track_num
       trck[1] = strckList[j][1]; //track_desc
      
       
       List<String[]> get_trckDate = pcr.get_trckDet(co_no,proj_cde,phase,lotNum,purcNum,trckTyp,trck[0]);
       if(get_trckDate.size()>0){
            for(int k = 0; k < get_trckDate.size(); k++){
                trck[2] = get_trckDate.get(k)[0];
                trck[3] = get_trckDate.get(k)[1];
            }
       }else{
           trck[2] = "";
           trck[3] = "";
       }
    
    %>
    <tr>
    
        <td align="center"><%=trck[0]%></td>
        <td><%=trck[1]%></td>
        <td id="trckDte" align ="center"> <input type="date" value="<%=trck[2]%>"/></td>
        <td id="trckRmks" align="center"> <input type="text" style="width:90%" value="<%=trck[3]%> "/> 
        
        
    </tr>
    <%}%>
 
   </table> 
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>

<form id="redirect" action="SPALoan.jsp" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="proj_cde" id="proj_cde" value="<%=proj_cde%>">
<input type="hidden" name="phase"   id="phase"   value="<%=phase%>">
<input type="hidden" name="lotNum"   id="lotNum"   value="<%=lotNum%>">
<input type="hidden" name="co_no" id="co_no" value="<%=co_no%>">
<input type="hidden" id="date_new" name="date_new" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" id="remarks" name="remarks" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="UPDATE"> 
</form>
</form>
</body>
 </html>

 //update info from jsp to database 

 public void updtrckDet(List<String> storeForm, String coNo, String projCde, String trckDte, String 
 trckRmks, String phasNum, String lotNum, String purcNum, String trckTyp, String trckNum){
   try {
    String sql = "UPDATE  c"+coNo+".crdtdf SET "
               + " crx_track_dte='"+storeForm.get(0)+"',"
               + " crx_track_rmks='"+storeForm.get(1)+"',"
               + "WHERE crx_proj_cde = '"+projCde+"' "
               + "  AND crx_lot_num  = '"+lotNum+"' "
               + "  AND crx_purc_num = '"+purcNum+"' "
               + "  AND crx_phase_num = '"+phasNum+"' " 
               + "  AND crx_track_typ = '"+trckTyp+"' "
               + "  AND crx_track_num = '"+trckNum+"' ";
   System.out.println("Execute = "+sql);
   super.execUpdate(sql, false);
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }


 public void updcrdtdf1(List<String> storeForm, String co_no, String projCde, String phaseNum)throws 
SQLException{
    try{
        String sql = "UPDATE c"+co_no+".crdtdf SET "
                + "crx_track_dte='"+storeForm.get(0)+"', crx_track_rmks='"+storeForm.get(1)+"',";
       System.out.println("Execute= "+sql);
       super.execUpdate(sql, false);
     }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
        
  } 


 public void insertcrdtdf(List<String> storeForm, String co_no){
     System.out.println("/*** insertcrdtdf ***/");
    String sql = "INSERT INTO c"+co_no+".crdtdf (crx_track_typ, crx_proj_cde, crx_phase_num, 
                  crx_lot_num,"
                  + "crx_purc_num, crx_track_num, crx_track_dte,"
                  + "crx_track_rmks) VALUES"
                  + "('"+storeForm.get(0)+"',"
                  + "'"+storeForm.get(1)+"', ";
                  super.execUpdate(sql,false);
               }

public void upd_trckDet(String co_no, String trckTyp, String projCde, String 
phaseNum, String lotNum, String purcNum, String trckNum, String trckDte, 
String trckRmks ) throws SQLException {
     System.out.println("upd_trckDet");
try {
        String sqlcheck = "SELECT crx_lot_num FROM c"+co_no+".crdtdf WHERE 
                           crx_proj_cde = '"+projCde+"' + " AND crx_phase_num 
                           = '"+phaseNum+"' AND crx_lot_num = '"+lotNum+"'";
        String check = super.execStr(sqlcheck, false);
        System.out.println("check: " + check);
        String sql = "";
        if(check.equals("")){
        sql = "INSERT INTO c"+co_no+".crdtdf (crx_track_typ, crx_proj_cde, 
               crx_phase_num, crx_lot_num, crx_purc_num, crx_track_num, 
               crx_track_dte, crx_track_rmks) "
            + " VALUES ('"+trckTyp+"', '"+projCde+"', '"+phaseNum+"', 
             '"+lotNum+"', '"+purcNum+"', '"+trckNum+"', '"+trckDte+"', 
             '"+trckRmks+"')";
        super.execUpdate(sql,false);
    } else {
        sql = "UPDATE c"+co_no+".crdtdf SET "+trckDte+" = '"+trckRmks+"' 
               WHERE crx_proj_cde = '"+projCde+"'"
            + " AND crx_phase_num = '"+phaseNum+"' AND crx_lot_num = 
             '"+lotNum+"'";
        super.execUpdate(sql,false);
    }               
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this id selector `$('#spaloan').submit()`? Your form id is `<form id="redirect" action="SPALoan.jsp" method="POST">`

Comment: in the code I have <form id="spaloan" action="SPALoan.jsp" method="POST">

Comment: OK, i see it now, thanks. What are the alerts and console.logs that are executed. Until where does it fail ? Can you share all the logs that you see?

Comment: In the console the query does not executed...and there's no error shown in the console. The alert display "Update record" and "Are you sure you want to save this record?" but when I check in the database there's no record. After we clicked save button in the jsp page, it will be null and does not hold the value entered.

Comment: `it will be null`, what does `it` means? It seems to be the form is submiting to where it should. Where does this action `SPALoan.jsp` leads to? Is it being hit?

Comment: it will be null - the value that we enter in the date and remarks column for example will be blank again after save button has been clicked. It does not hold the data we enter..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216549/discussion-between-jumping-monkey-and-mambo).